# The boundary of a cone isn't a smooth manifold

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $C=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3|z>\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\}$ be a cone in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Prove that the boundary $M=\partial C$ isn't a smooth manifold.

I can see that this question was already asked - [Prove: The boundary of the set $\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | z > \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\}$ isn't a smooth manifold.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1816270/prove-the-boundary-of-the-set-x-y-z-in-mathbbr3-z-sqrtx2y2)
Buthe didn't get any answer...

Comment: One quick and intuitive answer should be: there's no tangent plane at the origin.

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us what exact definition of "smooth manifold" you're using. Because $\partial C$ is homeomorphic (via the map $(x, y, z) \mapsto (x, y)$) to something that *is* a smooth manifold (namely $\Bbb R^2$) under just about every definition, but it's not the image of a smooth embedding of that manifold. So when you say it "isn't a smooth manifold," I need to know what constitutes "being" a smooth manifold in order to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $M$ fails to be a smooth *submanifold* of ${\mathbb R}^3$. The dimension of $\partial C$ qua submanifold would have to be $2$. In this case for each point $p\in M$ there would have to be a window $W$ centered at $p$ such that $M\cap W$ possesses a $C^1$ representation
$$f:\quad U\to{\mathbb R}^3,\qquad (u,v)\to f(u,v)$$
with $U\subset{\mathbb R}^2$ a neighborhood of the origin and $f(0,0)=p$. In the case at hand there is no such window for $p=0\in M$.

Comment: Hey,What is $U$?